# Unable to plot the data point using Bokeh and Python- shows empty layout

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh

I have a dataframe that has the following values. I am looking to plot them on an interactive graph using Bokeh.

```
locs = ['a', 'b', 'c']
prime_vals = [1000, 54, 457]
sub_vals = [0, 112, 34]
my_dict = {'loc' : locs, 'prime' : prime_vals, 'sub' : sub_vals}
df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
df
```

*I want the 'prime' and 'sub' to be two different checkboxes in the visualization. One could select both of them (prime and sub) and see the values with respect to 'loc' or see their values individually.
Below is the code I have, but it gives me the below image only- without any values. 
[image: Empty visualization from Bokeh]

```
p = figure(plot_width=1200, plot_height = 800)
aline = p.line(df["locs"], df['prime_vals'], line_width=2, 
color=Viridis4[0])
bline = p.line(df["locs"], df['sub_vals'], line_width=2, 
color=Viridis4[3])

p.yaxis.axis_label = 'x - axis label '
p.xaxis.axis_label = 'y - axis label'
legend = Legend(items=[("Prime",   [aline]),("Sub", [bline])], location=(0, 450))

t = Title()
t.text = 'Prime and sub roles over various offices'
p.title = t

p.add_layout(legend, 'left')

checkboxes = CheckboxGroup(labels=list(['Prime', 'Sub']), active=[0, 1])
callback = CustomJS(code="""aline.visible = false; // aline and etc.. are 
                        bline.visible = false; // passed in from args
                        // cb_obj is injected in thanks to the callback
                        if (cb_obj.active.includes(0)){aline.visible = true;} 
                            // 0 index box is aline
                        if (cb_obj.active.includes(1)){bline.visible = true;} """,                            
                args={'aline': aline, 'bline': bline})
checkboxes.js_on_click(callback)
output_file('some_name.html')
show(row(p, checkboxes))
```

I am unable to understand why the data points are not being plotted.

Comment: Do you have anything in the JavaScript console?

Comment: @EugenePakhomov No, there is no javascript code that I have written. Bokeh manages it.

Comment: That's not what I asked. Run the code, get to the step where you see the empty plot, open the JavaScript console in the same tab where you see the plot, and see if there are any errors/warnings.